# Access to Azure "root" directory producing 404

Tags: azure, dns

ANSWERED THIS MYSELF, BELOW.

I'm buying an SSL Certificate from TheSSLStore.

To authorize my request they need to be able to resolve `mydomain.net/randomstring.htm`.

The "actual" site is at `afunnydomainname.azurewebsites.net`.

The specific problem is that I can access the `randomstring.htm` file in `www.mydomain.net` but not `mydomain.net`.  And it's got to be `mydomain.net/randomstring.htm`, because TheSSLStore has a robot that looks for it there.

I have the following DNS records at my domain registrar that point to Azure, shown here.

`www.mydomain.net` => `afunnydomainname.azurewebsites.net` ("CNAME" record)
`*.mydomain.net` => `999.999.999.99` ("A" record, pointing to the real IP address)
`mydomain.net` => `999.999.999.99` ("A" record, pointing to the real IP address)

These have all propagated, and both `www.mydomain.net` and `mydomain.net` are listed in the "Bring External Domains" for afunnydomainname at Azure

When I point FileZilla at `afunnydomainname.azurewebsites.net`, I see this directory structure:

/
   LogFiles
   site
      wwwroot

In the "/", "site", and "wwwroot" directories, I have placed the `randomstring.htm` file, along with a `web.config` file that has `<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />;`

I can see both files in all three levels in FileZilla.

When I put `www.mydomain.net` in a browser address bar, I can see the directory  with `randomstring.htm` and `web.config`.

When I put `www.mydomain.net/randomstring.htm` in a browser address bar the file opens and I can see the authorization code that TheSSLStore is looking for.

If I put `mydomain.net` in the address bar I get 404.

If I put `mydomain.net/randomstring.htm` in the address bar I get 404.

SO, it seems like
a) mydomain.net may not be DNS'ing properly to the "real" root directory on Azure,

 b) OR, I don't understand where the "real root directory" is in this scenario, 
c) or something else.

Question:  What might be the problem and how might I fix it to get 'mydomain.net/randomstring.htm' to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

My Answer:

Was found at this site, from google search "azure A record 404"

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2013/10/01/404-file-or-directory-not-found-when-mapping-custom-domain-to-a-windows-azure-web-site-server-error.aspx

In short, going through the management console in the link above, instead of the new portal, I was able to get the `mydomain.net` exeternal domain associated with the `afunnydomainname.azurewebsites.net` site.

So, what happened with the portal "Bring External Domains" function? Did I not press the "save" button?  Not likely, since I went in and checked that `mydomain.net` was there, at least a couple of times, while trying to figure this out.

I hate to think that the management console could do that function more reliably than the portal, but you never know...